What role should victims have in determining punishment for crimes?
If we care about retributive justice , that is the principle of proportional penalty , are victims the best judges of what penalties to hand out ? Since the goal is to cause equal suffering to the victim by taking something important from the perpetrator. Is equal suffering an appropriate measures of proportionality ? Assuming we can calculate what can make someone suffer

Welcome to this forum. While there may be some philosophical writing in justice, this question still seems political rather than philosophical, and too open ended and opinion based for this site.

Isn't ethics and politics separable ? Depending on the ethical theory.

Does this answer your question? Is it logical to seek revenge?

Also see https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/105094 also https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/legal-punishment/ for a general overview of why and how to punish.

To cause equal suffering is a naive goal, since it would require suffering  be assessed and inflicted with an unattainable degree of objectivity and uniformity. Suffering is personal and subjective- an experience one victim might consider to be an unparalleled outrage might be borne with quiet stoicism by another, so the first might call for the perpetrator to be locked away for good, while the second might recommend a pardon. How would you know that the first victim was not merely being vindictive in their claims for retribution? How would you guard against the possibility that victims might be 'leant on' in some way to recommend  light punishments? It might seem odd to most people to have a legal system in which the punishments meted out for comparable crimes varied enormously because they were determined by the inconsistent whims of victims. How would you handle sentencing in relation to murder, where the victim was unable to give an account of any suffering they endured? In any event, the idea that sentences should be determined by retributive considerations might be considered a form of barbarism. A more enlightened society might consider that the aim of good sentencing should be to promote public safety, discourage offences and rehabilitate offenders.

In that order. The first is vastly the most important, the second is sometimes said to be ineffective, and the third may well be impossible, or unnecessary if the person caused the harm without really intending to (we punish people for being incautious or inattentive also). I would reduce it to: did they mean to do it? Yes: keep them out of society permanently, No: let them out on parole. We used to send prisoners to Australia, but it got full :-)
