# Origin of Clothing

Tags: ethics

I have been wondering about if no one has clothes on, would there be anyone who feels shy?
So few questions pop up in my mind.
Why do we wear clothes? How did the clothing history start? What are philosophical views on clothing?Whether being nude is good or bad?

Comment: We covered these issues here: 'How do ethicists tackle the question "Is it immoral to have sex in public places?" Is it possible to use rational and empirical ideas to answer?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77168/how-do-ethicists-tackle-the-question-is-it-immoral-to-have-sex-in-public-places/77170#77170 Humans are very unusual in having sex in private, & this seems to be linked to better social cooperation by limiting sex-related activities to the private sphere, & nudity reveals excitation, & potentially fertility. In nudist resorts different norm & people don't feel shy

Comment: But clothing is also "symbolic" (like tattoos) and the symbolic aspects is paramount in society.

Comment: The question, "Why do we wear clothes?" is certainly at least partially answered by reference to requiring protection from the environment.  This would include warmth retention in cooler climates, UV protection from the sun, and even camouflaged while hunting (to conceal predation) and gathering (so as not to become prey).

Comment: Ian Gilligan at the site academia.edu has a dozen of papers and some book chapters on clothing, including origin, shame, etc .

Answer (score 0):

According to Chinese history, from 2500 BC, ancient humans began to explore how to use silk to spin clothes. Before clothes were invented. People used foliage to block. Wearing clothes may be an instinct for people to protect themselves

Comment: Evidence? The Tarkhan Dreas is a linen dress from 2800BC, indicating sophisticated weaving was already present then. There are bone needles from the Clovis people of Northern Europe 20,000 years ago, & it's thought stitched kayaks with spray covers were what allowed them to be the first humans to North America, following abundant fish & seals. Lice evidence suggests clothes emerged 170,000 years ago, (probably) predating modern humans https://www.sciencefocus.com/science/when-did-humans-first-start-wearing-clothes/